# How to access and control other window ..java?

Tags: java, swing, listener

I like to do a program which can control other program(window). I would like that my program automatically click button and get others states. But for now i am just asking how to access to this other program/process with java.

Comment: Are you talking about GUI unit testing?

Comment: the other program is child process?

Comment: Just saying maybe you could do some research before coming here. And maybe some detail about how you're trying to do it. Try java Robot Class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try java.awt.Robot

How to press keys

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Robot robot = new Robot();

static int keyInput[] = { KeyEvent.VK_SPACE };
robot.keyPress(keyInput[i]);
```

How to manipulate mouse

```
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

robot.mouseMove(300, 550);//MOVING MOUSE
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); // CLICKING MOUSE
```

`InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK` = left button

`InputEvent.BUTTON2_MASK` = middle button

`InputEvent.BUTTON3_MASK` = right button

[Here's](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/54172-robot-class/#axzz2EYmtmdJu) a good tutorial to start

Answer (score 2):

Try have look at the Java `Robot` Class.

Comment: Oops. Sorry nice answer. Was typing on my phone. Didn't see you got there before me :-)